# Alternative to glossaries?

Tags: glossaries

*UPDATE:* I have been using glassaries for some time now, and kind of got used to it. It's not as bad as I at first thought.

Is there a nicer alternative to `glossaries` package? It's a pita to use. Documentation is lacking examples, some commands don't do anything (like `\glssee`), it is hard to customize (why can't I make my glossary a simple section?), it is stateful - I have to call `makeglossaries` in a certain place, and also the syntax for defining new entries is ugly:

```
 \newglossaryentry{blah}{name=blah, description={blabh lbah blah}}
```

It's like xml.

No offense to the creators, but I am just curious if anyone else feels this way and if there are alternatives?

Comment: I hope you both mean "lovely" for "like xml"

Comment: `\glssee` does ‘something’ if you use it _after_ `\makeglossaries`.

Comment: You are writing a book-type document and want your glossary to appear in a simple section? Try, for example, `\usepackage[section=section, numberedsection]{glossaries}`.

Comment: Undoubtedly, the `glossaries` package is rather complex, but, in my experience, it enables you to realize nearly anything related to glossaries, lists of acronyms, notations etc. Since the `glossaries` package includes tree-like styles it might also serve as a replacement for many index-related packages. Moreover, I haven’t seen any package that supports `xindy` in a comparable manner.

Comment: What is this xindy? It is mentioned everywhere in the docs, but never explained what it is or why one would use it.

Comment: Traditionally, the `makeindex` program is used for sorting indexes and glossaries. `xindy` is an advanced alternative to `makeindex` that supports multiple languages and input encodings (e.g. UTF-8).

Comment: @mhp Do I still need it if I use xelatex?

Comment: Yes. The input of both `makeindex` and `xindy` is simply a file written by LaTeX. It’s not relevant whether the underlying TeX engine supports Unicode natively (such as XeTeX and LuaTeX) or not (such as pdfTeX).

Comment: Would you prefer to have a command that had at least 18 optional arguments? That's the alternative to `key`=`value` syntax. The `glossaries` package comes with [21 sample files](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/) and a [beginners' guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.html) for people who find the main user manual too large. If something doesn't work, provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?lq=1) rather than just saying it's a pita.

Comment: Awesome question. I hope there is a good alternative available.

Comment: @Dan if there were a good alternative available, people would surely be using it.  so perhaps the people who don't like `glossaries` should actually _write_ code that does what they fancy.  (something with lots of options, but none of this new-fangled key-value stuff, and so on.)

Comment: @wasteofspace the key/value is not my issue. The need for using Perl and doing things outside of the TeX file is the problem. I actually think the stuff done in the TeX file with `glossaries` is quite simple. It just won't display without first running a Perl utility against the glossaries file. This is a problem for folks like me who are writing code so that users don't have to even know what LaTeX is in order to generate documents with it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative to a pita.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lstdoc,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\alist{}

\let\sort\lst@BubbleSort 
\def\addtolist#1#2{
  \lst@lAddTo\alist{#2}
}

\long\gdef\addterm#1#2{\addtolist\alist{#1,}}

\def\gentry#1#2{%
\long\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{\textbf{#1}: #2}
\addterm{#1}{#2}
\sort\alist
}

\def\PrintGlossary{%
  \@for \i:=\alist\do{%
  \csname\i\endcsname\par}
}
%example
\gentry{electrolyte}{Substance containing free ions that make t
        he substance electrically conductive}
\gentry{battery}{\lipsum[3]}
\gentry{poles}{\lipsum[1]}
% print the glossary
\section{Glosary}
\PrintGlossary


\battery
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Add ingredients to suit.

It provides one non-xml command:

```
  \gentry{<term>}{<description>}
```

...and it does not need Perl. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, but it's missing the equivalent of the `\gls` command, and I would also like to do cross-referencing. E.g. **car** _see vehicle_

Comment: `\gentry{car}{see vehicle}`.

Comment: So.. how would I use a glossary term in text? Or do you mean that this is only for defining a glossary section at the end, without page numbers of where it occurred?

Answer (score 5):

I changed the code above, so that you can do cross references:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{lstdoc,lipsum} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document} 
\makeatletter 
\def\alist{} 

\let\sort\lst@BubbleSort  
\def\addtolist#1#2{ 
  \lst@lAddTo\alist{#2} 
} 

\long\gdef\addterm#1#2{\addtolist\alist{#1,}} 

\def\gentry#1#2{% 
\long\expandafter\gdef\csname.#1\endcsname{\hypertarget{target#1}{\textbf{#1}: #2}}
\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{\hyperlink{target#1}{#1}}
\addterm{#1}{#2} 
\sort\alist 
}

\def\gentryP#1#2#3{% 
\expandafter\gdef\csname#3\endcsname{\hyperlink{target#1}{#3}}
\long\expandafter\gdef\csname.#1\endcsname{\hypertarget{target#1}{\textbf{#1}: #2}}
\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{\hyperlink{target#1}{#1}}
\addterm{#1}{#2} 
\sort\alist 
} 

\def\PrintGlossary{%
  \section{Glosary} 
  \ 

  \@for \i:=\alist\do{% 
  \csname.\i\endcsname\par} 

  \newpage
}


%example 
\gentry{electrolyte}{Substance containing free ions that make t 
        he substance electrically conductive}
% use gentryP if the plural is irregular         
\gentryP{battery}{\lipsum[3]}{batteries} 
\gentry{poles}{\lipsum[1]}

% print the glossary 
\PrintGlossary 

\section{normal text}

\electrolyte s are used nearly everywhere.



\newpage

\battery is the singular. but sometimes you need the plural \batteries.



\makeatother 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work: https://www.writelatex.com/322948pgpznd

Answer (score 1):

The `datagidx` package in the `datatool` bundle might a good solution for you.

Datagidx is an improved version of the code discussed in [this article](http://latex-community.org/component/content/article/55-latex-general/456-glossary-without-makeindex).

Here is some [package documentation](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) and a [sample document](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/samples/sample-gidx.pdf).

I have not tried this myself yet, but it is the one I have settled on trying as my first approach because I don't like that the `glossaries` package has external dependencies.

Edit: I have now tried this on one project. It works works nicely but can be a slight bit confusing at first, but I haven't tried any of the other solutions to this so I can't really compare them.