# Table of contents broken with Koma Script and lstdoc

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, koma-script

There seems to be some negative interaction between Koma Script (using version 3.11a) and the `lstdoc` package in my example document. The MWE works nicely when I comment out `\usepackage{lstdoc}` but when I include it the formatting of the table of contents is messed up. Here is the example document:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
titlepage
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lstdoc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{test1}
test test
\end{document}
```

The output without `lstdoc` looks as follows
[image]

whereas with the package included this happens:
[image]

Is there any workaround to this problem? I want to the line because I am using the alternative to the `glossaries` package from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59757/alternative-to-glossaries) which requires the `lstdoc` package. I noticed that `hyperref` is also pulled in if `lstdoc` is used but `hyperref` alone does not cause any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `lstdoc.sty` redefines some of the `\l@...` family of commands in charge of typesetting the entries for the sectional units in the ToC. For example, `\l@section` is defined in `lstdoc.sty` as

```
\newcommand*\l@section[2]{%
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup}
```

whereas the definition for `\l@section` in `scrbook.cls` is

```
\newcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

In order to recover the original definitions you can redefine the `\l@...` commands in the preamble of your document to be the ones used for `scrbook.cls`. So for example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lstdoc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{test1}
test test
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

which is (up to the colored hyperlink) the original formatting. Similar redefinitions will have to be made for some of the other `\l@...` commands corresponding to the other sectional units that will go to the ToC and which \l@... commamds are redefined by lstdoc.sty.

The following example code shows these redefinitions necessary to obtain the original formatting for ToC entries from `\chapter` down to `\subparagraph`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lstdoc}

% all sectional units will be numbered and will go to the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\bprot@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\bprot@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Test Paragraph}
\subparagraph{Test Subparagraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Now the table of contents is restored to it's old beauty.

Comment: Since KOMA-Script 2015/01/14 v3.15 you should not longer redefine `\l@…` using `\bprot@dottedtocline`. The better (and easier) solution would be to use `\RedeclareSectionCommands{section,subsection,subsubsection}`. Can you change/add this to the answer?