# Alternative to glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, texlipse

I was wondering if there are any alternatives to the glossaries package. My problem is the following:

1) I'm a [TeXlipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/texlipse) user and for what I was able to understand, TeXlipse does not support the glossaries package, unless I am willing to adopt some [less orthodox approaches](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52549/79812).

2) Leaving TeXlipse is not an option for me, at least for now.

3) [Other answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59762/79812) that I found regarding this subject did not work properly for me.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: the perl part of makeglossaries is surely optional it just automates calling `makeindex` with the right options but you could not do that and just call makeindex directly

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is indeed optional. There's also a Lua alternative `makeglossaries-lite.lua` (v4.17+) or if shell escape is enabled there's the `automake` package option (v4.08+).