# Alternative to glossaries (abbreviations)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm searching for an alternative to **glossaries** that I can use with MikTex 2.9, specifically in TeXWorks. It may not depend on any external program due to security restrictions.

I only need a functionality that allows abbreviations, glossary entries not definitely needed (although this is almost the same, technically, I assume).

I've seen [Alternative to glossaries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59757/alternative-to-glossaries), but this would not work for me as I need something that allows me to use a command like

```
\gls{glossname}
```

To reference the glossary entries.

Ideally, it would also have the capability of listing the pages where the entry is used.

Anybody able to help me here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use [`\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1) instead of `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossaries`, you can use the `glossaries` package without the need for any external programs.

Comment: Wonderful, works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

(Converting my comment into an answer.) It's possible to use the `glossaries` package without using an external indexing application ([Option 1](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1) in the user manual). You just need to use `\makenoidxglossaries` instead of `\makeglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries` (or `\printnoidxglossary`) instead of `\printglossaries` (or `\printglossary`).

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
 description={an example}}
\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample} and \gls{html}.

\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

Alternatively:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
 description={an example}}
\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample} and \gls{html}.

\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```